# how to use 2 variable php without slash

Tags: php, variables

How i can use 2 variable for this code ?
I set my url website in tbl_setting : localhost/directory/
Now i'want Redirect if some Value = someValue 
for example :

```
  <?php 
  $siteurl = $rowsetting['url']; // localhost/directory/ 
  $someone = "1";
  $sometwo = "1";
  if($someone==$sometwo) {
  Redirect("$siteurl/dashboard");
  }
?>
```

but it Redirect localhost/directory//dashboard (two slashes)
and if i remove / in Redirect :

```
Redirect("$siteurldashboard");
```

the new variable : $siteurldashboard not found

Comment: `$someone` will never equal `$sometwo`

Comment: just concatenate that string properly, of course it'll be interpreted as in whole `"$siteurldashboard"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ghost said, just concatenate strings properly :

`Redirect($siteurl . "/dashboard");`